# Not able to access Datagrid datacontext from datatemplate

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Legs}" Grid.Row="1"
                        DataContext="{Binding}"   
                        Tag="{Binding}"  
                        CanUserAddRows="False"                          
                        CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                        x:Name="statusGrid"  
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"   
                        RowStyle="{StaticResource GridRowStyle}"            
                        >
```

And then

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Status">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Height="16" MaxHeight="14" Width="14" MaxWidth="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Image.Source>
                                            <MultiBinding>
                                                <Binding Path="SwapswireBuyerStatusText"/>
                                                <Binding Path="SwapswireSellerStatusText"/>
                                                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                    <Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor AllGoodPath="/Resources/Done.png" 
                                                            InProgressPath="/Resources/Go.png" WarningPath="/Resources/Warning.png">
                                                                **<Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor.DealProp>
                                                            <Control:DealObject Deal="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=Tag}"/>
                                                                </Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor.DealProp>**
                                                    </Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor>
                                                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Image.Source>
                                    </Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Following is my Depenency property on Convertor

```
public class DealObject : DependencyObject
    {
        public static DependencyProperty TradedDecimalsProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("TradedDecimals", typeof(Int32), typeof(DealObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
        public static DependencyProperty DealProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Deal", typeof(CMBSTrade), typeof(DealObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(new CMBSTrade()));
        public CMBSTrade Deal
        {
            get { return (CMBSTrade)GetValue(DealProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DealProperty, value); }
        }
        public Int32 TradedDecimals
        {
            get { return (Int32)GetValue(TradedDecimalsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TradedDecimalsProperty, value); }
        }
    }

[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(BitmapImage))]
    public class SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public String AllGoodPath { get; set; }
        public String InProgressPath { get; set; }
        public String WarningPath { get; set; }
        private DealObject _DealProp = null;
        public DealObject DealProp
        {
            get { return _DealProp; }
            set { _DealProp = value; }
        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            String path = WarningPath;
            try
            {                
                if (null != DealProp && null != DealProp.Deal && null != values && values.Length == 2)
                {
                    String str1 = System.Convert.ToString(values[0]);
                    String str2 = System.Convert.ToString(values[1]);
                    if (DealProp.Deal.Swapswire)
                    {
                        switch (MBSConfirmationHelper.GetSwapswireStatus(str1, str2, MBSConfirmationHelper.GetParticipantType(DealProp.Deal)))
                        {
                            case DealExecutionStatus.InProgress:
                                path = InProgressPath; break;
                            case DealExecutionStatus.ActionRequired:
                            case DealExecutionStatus.Error:
                                path = WarningPath;
                                break;
                            case DealExecutionStatus.Executed:
                                path = AllGoodPath;
                                break;
                            case DealExecutionStatus.NotApplicable:
                                path = String.Empty;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else path = String.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)? null : new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not Implemented");
        }
    }
```

in the above XAML code... I am trying to access datagrid's Tag property, the binding is working for the object is always comming null. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do not use the `Tag` property. Its bad style. use DataContext instead. Are your `DealObject.Deal` is a `DependencyProperty`? Show the description code of your `DealObject`.

Comment: Ok included my Converter code as well. Thanks for the tag suggestion... but it doesn't work. The object being passed to convertor is null.

Comment: I think that the your root problem should be described here. You should to write what do you want to do, and show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). I suppose that SO community can find better solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is evident from your code...

```
 <Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor.DealProp>
   <Control:DealObject 
         Deal="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                        Path=Tag}"/>
 </Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor.DealProp>**
```

**Your converter or any property within the converter can never be part of the visual tree and hence the binding wont work on it** even if your deal object or the converter itself is a `DependencyObject`!

Please revise your binding ...

Why does your converter need to have a property that needs binding? You already have `MultiBinding`, so involve this binding as part of that ....

```
     <MultiBinding>
         <Binding Path="SwapswireBuyerStatusText"/>
         <Binding Path="SwapswireSellerStatusText"/>

         **<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"
                  Path="Tag"/>**

         <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <Control:SwapswireStatusImagePathConvertor 
                     AllGoodPath="/Resources/Done.png"
                     InProgressPath="/Resources/Go.png" 
                     WarningPath="/Resources/Warning.png" />
         </MultiBinding.Converter>
     </MultiBinding>
```

Now your converter receives all the 3 values that it needs ...

```
     String str1 = System.Convert.ToString(values[0]);
     String str2 = System.Convert.ToString(values[1]);
     ** this.DealProp = new DealObject();
     this.DealProp.Deal = values[2] as CMBSTrade; **

     if (DealProp.Deal.Swapswire) 
     {
           ....
     }
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: True, I don't require a The deal properly on the converter object, I should have used the multibinding itself. Thanks for your help. But just to understand, what the options available in such an scenario. For example, I even tried creating a framework element as grid resource and using that as static resrouce on binding, something like <Image.Resources> <FrameworkElement x:Key="dealTunnel" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Image}}}"/> </Image.Resources> and  <Control:DealObject Deal="{Binding Source={StaticResource dealTunnel}, Path=DataContext}"/>

Comment: I am sorry; my bad... above tunnel does work. I've been doing an mistake; my bad. Thanks a lot WPF-IT :)

Comment: Any options if is fine as long as the **element is hosted in the visual tree** (not even Logical Tree). These resources should be part fo the visual tree for them to work correctly.